# Get method in a implemented Linked List, Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to implement a Linked List of integers from zero (not using existing LinkedList class).

This is the code:

*A single Link class*

```
public class Link {
    public int data;
    public Link nextLink;

    public Link(int d1) {
        data = d1;      
    }

    public void printListElements(){
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

*and the LinkedList class*

```
public class LinkedList {
    private Link first;
    public LinkedList(){
        first = null;
    }

    public void add(int data1){
        Link linklist = new Link(data1);
        linklist.nextLink = first;
        first = linklist;
    }

    public void printList(){
    Link current=first;
    System.out.println("List Elements are ");
    while(current!=null){
       current.printListElements();
       current=current.nextLink;
    }
  }
}
```

As you see it has already *add* and *printList* method. But how do i make a get() method, which returns a value of a specific index.

This is what i mean:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    LinkedList MyList = new LinkedList();

    MyList.add(1);
    MyList.add(2);
    MyList.add(3);
    MyList.add(4);

    System.out.println("MyList.get(0)"); // should get 1
        System.out.println("MyList.get(1)"); // should get 2 etc
}
```

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Well, since it's a linked list, you don't have any way to directly access any element except the first one, right? So the only way to do it is to start there and step through (by successively following the links to the next element) until you reach the element specified by the index, and then return that. The easiest way to do that is with a loop.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that with your current implementation. Because you are adding every new node as the head node.

If you change your `add()` so that every new node is added as the last node then you can do that using your `index` value passed to `get()` as the loop counter.

Comment: Note that the best way to do this is by adding a 'last' field to keep track of the tail of the list; otherwise, you will have to step through the entire list just to add a new element on the end.

Answer (score 1):

In LinkedList you have your elements reverted.

```
public int get(int i) {
    int n = indexOf(first); // count-1 actually
    Link current = first;
    while (n > i) {
        --n;
        current = current.nextLink;
    }
    return current.data;
}

private int indexOf(Link link) {
    if (link == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1 + indexOf(link.nextLink);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a dual linked list:

```
class Node<T> {
   Node<T> next;
   Node<T> prev;
   T data;
}

class LinkedList<T> {
   Node<T> head;
   Node<T> tail;
   int count;
}
```

Your add method would actual just create a new node, and attach it to the "next" pointer of the tail, reassign the tail, and increment the count. (yes you could do this with a single linked list as well as long as you have a tail pointer)

Which this approach, add is a constant time operation and preserves insertion order (unlike the single linked list approach you were taking, where insertion order is not preserved).

Also, you could optimize the "get" to see if the requested index is closer to the head or tail, and traverse from the appropriate end to get the node you want.

I assume this is homework, so i don't want to give the entire code away.